# How much time does it take to move resources to a new Resource Group in Azure?

Tags: azure, migration

I am concerned about the downtime that might be needed as both source and target resource groups are actively used.

[Azure Portal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NERDz.png)
Both resource groups are associated with same subscription. Any other pointers one should keep in mind related to this warning?

Updated: I am targeting compute resources - VM and images are to be moved. I ran a quick scan to see what all could be moved, got a green for my compute resources.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to move azure images and VMs to a new resource group under same subscription. If anybody needs any specific input please let me know I'll be happy to elaborate all that I can.